# How can we connfigure log4j2 logs with spring boot actuator?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2, spring-boot-actuator

I want to see log4j log on browser link.
I found out that spring boot actuator provides browser-based log endPoint but I am not sure how it will be configured with log4j.
Is there any other API which I can integrate into my application to see real time logs in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It work for me once I update the application.properties as below.

`logging.file=logfile.log
logging.path=/home/developer/logs`

see the doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-logger-configuration

**It says**: Returns the contents of the logfile (if logging.file or logging.path properties have been set). Supports the use of the HTTP Range header to retrieve part of the log file’s content.